# What does "mandate" mean in following sentences?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning

I couldn't comprehend the meaning of "mandate" in following sentences;

1. For post-certified aircraft, these actions should be specified as service information by the TCH or included in an updated ALS and may be **mandated** by Airworthiness Directives.
2. The initial flaw for damage tolerance analysis of the windmilling phase need not be greater than the flaw size determined as the detectable flaw size plus growth under well phase spectrum loads for one inspection period for **mandated** inspections.
3. Determining the necessary amount of physical separation distance is essential. But because each system design and aeroplane model can be unique, and because manufacturers have differing design standards and installation techniques, CS 25.1707 does not **mandate** specific separation distances.

In the last sentence **mandate** is used as synonym of oblige, but there is no [*definition*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mandate_2) like.

Comment: Have you tried a different dictionary? Dictionary.com seems to define it well enough.

Comment: Mandate — to require — is pretty clear from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mandate

Comment: Both dictionaries provides meaning used in the sentences. I don't know why but _macmillandictionary_ does not have the meaning "_to make obligatory_".

Comment: Flagging as off topic since the word is well defined by some dictionaries as whiskeychief has pointed out. Please feel free to edit the question if you need more clarification on the definition provided by Cambridge dictionary.